# nested list control upto 3 level in telerik report

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-reporting

I am developing web application in ASP.NET, this application have Reports so for reporting I am using telerik report library.
In this report I want show detail using list control and below is my object structure,

```
  public class ReportModel
  {

    public ReportModel()
    {
        Children = new List<Elements>();
    }

    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
    public string OfferName { get; set; }
    public List<Elements> Children { get; set; }
 }

 public class Elements
{
    public Elements()
    {
        Children = new List<Position>();
    }

    public int ElementId { get; set; }
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public List<Position> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public Position()
    {
        Children = new List<OfferItem>();
    }

    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public string PositionName { get; set; }

    public List<OfferItem> Children { get; set; }
}

public class OfferItem
{
    public int OfferItemId { get; set; }
    public string OfferItemName { get; set; }
}
```

Above is my object structure,those data I want to show in report, 
Please let me know how can I bind these multi-level data to list- nested-list-nested-list control.
Please let me know any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.